# What is coupond?

Tags: macos, malware, daemons

I restarted my Mac, running El Capitan, and got a pop up asking whether I wanted to allow "coupond" to accept incoming network connections. I said no. I rebooted and got the message again. I have no idea what I could have downloaded.

In my Library/LaunchAgents folder, not the ~/Library folder, there is an entry for com.coupons.coupond.plist .

Then in Libary/Application Support, there is a folder for Coupons. Within it is Uninstall Coupon Printing Software.app.

I assume I got some adware/malware, but malware bytes says there is nothing amiss.

How can I safely remove this and where could I have gotten it from?

Comment: Some online coupons require you to install software to print them, to make sure people don't try to duplicate the coupons or anything. This is probably harmless, but I'd recommend running the installer if you don't need to print any more.

Comment: Just uninstall it. Some websites use special printing software so you can't copy their coupons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have "adware" infection: download AdwareMedic (now called Malwarebytes) from  http://www.adwaremedic.com/index.php
Then run the scan.